# Write datatype for polynoms in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, polynomials

I've to write a datatype for polynoms in haskell.

The result should something like this:

```
[] = 0:0         [1:0] = 1:0           [3; 2; 1; 0; 0] = x2 + 2x + 3
[0:0] = 0:0     [-5; 22] = 22x - 5         [5; 0; 3; 0; 1] = x4 + 3x2 + 5
```

My try to declare a polynom datatype:

```
data Liste 
  = LeereListe 
  | Element a (List a)
  deriving (Show)

Polynom :: Liste Double
Polynom = Element 1 + (Element 2 * Element 2) + (Element 3 * Element 3 * Element 3)
```

My Errors:

```
4.hs:6:2: parse error on input `poly1'
:reload

4.hs:6:1:
    Invalid type signature: Polynom :: Liste Double
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

I don't know how to do handle this error.
What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey cause list is already defined i would use this definition:

```
data Polynom   = Polynom [(Double,Double)]
polyEval (Polynom []) a = 0
polyEval (Polynom (x:xs) ) a = (fst x) *a^(snd x) + polyEval (Polynom xs) a
```

So you didn't need to store all coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

First, `a` must be a variable in the data type, you can't use it unless it is declared.

```
data Liste a
  = LeereListe 
  | Element a (List a)
  deriving (Show)
```

Second, values must start with a lower case letter.  Since you didn't define `instance Num` or any convenience functions, we must create values structurally, using the type's constructors:

```
polynom :: Liste Double
polynom = Element 1 (Element 2 (Element 3 (Element 4 LeereListe)))
```

I think I might do it like this, without defining a new structure:

```
newtype Polynomial = Polynomial [Double] deriving Show

evaluate :: Polynomial -> Double -> Double
evaluate (Polynomial coeff) x = sum $ zipWith (*) (iterate (x*) 1) coeff
```

Comment: thanks for answear, it's not allowed to use functions from the libery. So I have to define it by myself, so I want to try something like that: [x,y,z] = x + y^2 + z^3